# What is the usual way to demonstrate confidence that one system converges faster than another?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, convergence, decision-theory

I have two computational agents which are attempting to learn the best policy for some decision problem. After 5000 samples, both agents converge on the optimal policy. (I.e their policy error is 0). The graph looks something like this (where the x-axis is the number of samples seen so far, Y-axis is the error, and red and blue plots are the first and second agent respectively)

[image: Policy error of two systems]

It seems like the blue agent converges on the optimal policy faster than the red one from this experiment. What is the usual way of convincing someone that this is indeed true?

The only analogous experience I have with this kind of hypothesis testing is a "t-test", where you would run the same experiment multiple times, get the mean value of each and attempt to reject that the hypothesis that both the systems are the same. However, I don't think this makes sense in my current scenario, as the final policy error of both agents is exactly the same at the end of each experiment (they both converge to 0). I am more interested in how quickly each converges *during* the experiment.